# Why would you want to convert an object to boolean when used in a boolean context?

Tags: javascript

I understand that `!!` converts anything to a boolean value, but why would you want to do this:

```
if (!!someObject) { ... }
```

When you can just do:

```
if (someObject) { ... }
```

EDIT:

Just to clarify, I'm simply asking why you would write code like in the first example, rather than that in the second example.  Are there any practical differences?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript

Comment: For example `return !!5` or `!!~arr.indexOf(n)`. There are many uses not just `if` statements.

Comment: @elclanrs I understand, but I was asking specifically about the use in the first example.

Comment: There's no real use for `!!` in `if` statements AFAIK. You can rely on truthyness or falsyness.

Comment: `!!` is only useful in an `if` when you want to perform a comparison, e.g. if you want to check two things are both truthy or both falsy you could do `if (!!a === !!b) {/*..*/}`. Edit: if that were for numbers, then it _could_ mean "`a` and `b` are both `0` OR `a` and `b` are both non-zero"

Comment: @PaulS. that makes sense, although this usage sounds pretty obscure :P

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a significant different between them. So, most likely, it's personal preference or to be explicit about the intent.

Though, it's possibly from an uncertainty/misunderstanding of how or when values are treated as a booleans.

But, both [`if` statements](http://es5.github.io/#x12.5) and [Logical NOT operators](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.9) use the internal `ToBoolean()`:

> If [`ToBoolean`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.2)([`GetValue`](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1)(*exprRef*)) is `true`, [...]

> Let *oldValue* be [`ToBoolean`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.2)([`GetValue`](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1)(*expr*))

The operators just add 2 more rounds of `ToBoolean()` with negation on top of the `if` statement's own use. But, the result is the same.